# Delete files with specific names from subfolders

Tags: java, file, io, directory

I have a main folder named as MainFolder reside in (C:) directory. In the main folder, I have 700 subfolders each of the 700 folders has the same files names. My aim is to delete each file named as(info.txt) and (full.png) from each of the sub directories. All the results after I searched delete either all the content of the folder or the folder itself. Does anyone have an idea how to approach it?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [so] I recommend you to visit the [tour] and see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can walk a file tree recursively and delete all files with that name:

```
 public void walk(String path) {
     File[] list = new File(path).listFiles();
     if (list == null) return;

     for (File f : list) {
         if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
             walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
         } else {
             if (f.getName().equals("info.txt") || f.getName().equals("full.png")) {
                 f.delete();
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you brother, when I tried it in the program it says (';' expected

incompatible types: File cannot be converted to File[]
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints))

Comment: Corrected the code. There was a . missing after `new File(path)`

Answer (score 0):

Use filefilters with file object. Then You can delete the files